# how to use command line argument to find .txt file that have common name

Tags: command-line, bash

I have multiple files in a directory called `files`. I have to read each .txt file from this directory:

```
abc123.txt
abc234.txt
abc345.txt
abc.txt
def123.txt
def234.txt
def345.txt
```

For example, when I type `./filter.sh abc` in the terminal, it will search for the `.txt` file whose name contains `abc`.

```
#!/bin/bash
 
input1=$1


find ./files -type f -name "*$input1*.txt"
```

my output look like this

```
./files/abc345.txt
./files/abc234.txt
./files/abc123.txt
./files/abc.txt
```

am I doing it correctly? And also, is it possible not to show `./files/` in the output? And why does my output show `abc345`, `abc234`, `abc123` instead of `abc123`, `abc234`, `abc345`?

Answer (score 9):

- *Yes, it is good.* But when you get more familiar with `find`, you will do it directly on the command line (instead of via a shellscript). I use shellscripts a lot, but mainly for bigger tasks (several command lines).
- You can strip the starting-point under which it was found:

  ```
  find ./files -type f -name "*$input1*.txt" -printf "%P\n"
  ```
- Finally you can sort the files afterwards:

  ```
  find ./files -type f -name "*$input1*.txt" -printf "%P\n" | sort
  ```
- If a small number or small files you can write the content to the terminal with

  ```
  find ./files -type f -name "*$input1*.txt" -exec echo "--- {}:" \; -exec cat {} \;
  ```

  The output can be redirected to a file by `> output.txt`

  ```
  find ./files -type f -name "*$input1*.txt" -exec echo "--- {}:" \; -exec cat {} \; > output.txt
  ```

  Scroll horizontally to see the end of this line.
- if many files or some big file, it may be better to view the files in less or maybe your favourite text editor,

  ```
  find ./files -type f -name "*$input1*.txt" -exec less {} \;
  ```

  and exit with 'q' from less between each file.
- `find` versus `ls`

  - **`find` is an advanced tool** that can find files [recursively] in a directory tree, and it has many options. It takes a long time to learn what can be done with it. See `man find` or maybe easier, see a tutorial via the internet.
  - **`ls` is a simpler tool**, that lists files at one directory level, usually the current level. It has also many options, but is quite **easy to use from the command line**. Please be aware, that `ls` can behave in a confusing way in shellscripts, particularly in combinations with other commands. See `man ls`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks it work! May i know how to read or print the content out from those txt file? i tried to do for about 1 day already still cannot figure out

Comment: With respect to point 1, if it is a recurring job, creating a shell script obviously is good practice.

Comment: @user15907922, What do you mean by read or print? Do you want to print everything to the terminal or view them in some tool or print to a paper printer?

Comment: print the content in the text file to the terminal.

Comment: @user15907922, I suggest a couple of methods to view the files. Will one of them work?

Comment: @sudodus yea it works. thanks a lot! And may i know how to copy those content in the .txt file into another .txt file? let say copy to copy.txt

Comment: You can **redirect** the output to the terminal into a file with `>`. I will show that by editing the answer.

Comment: thats work! thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like that and follow @sudodus advice to improve the output.

However `find` is a bit an overkill for your use case, you could simply use `ls`:

```
ls -1 files/abc*
```

To get of the directory name:

```
(cd files && ls -1 abc*)
```

Comment: but how to copy those content in the txt file into another .txt file?

Comment: what you mean? I don't see this part in your question. Do you want to do `cat files/abc*` or `less files/abc*` ?

Comment: its ok i solved it. thanks for helping!